# How do gsutil partial uploads work on the remote end?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

If I interrupt a `gsutil cp` of a 10GB object, I can resume that upload from where I left off. Clearly there is a partial object somewhere on the remote end. I'd like to know more info about those remote partial objects.

Do those partial uploads take up billable space on GCS? Are the partial objects viewable anywhere? Also, how long will partial objects stick around on GCS?

Answer (score 1):

I found documentation indicating that upload URIs expire in 1 week. No indication on if the partial uploads cost money, though:

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/upload#resumable

> Note: An upload URI expires after one week.